# How to install UnityVS 2012, and support Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unity-game-engine, unityvs

I just installed UnityVS 1.2.2 on the C drive:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\SyntaxTree\UnityVS\
```

My Visual Studio version is 2010 and it is installed on the D drive:

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\
```

My operating system is Windows XP.

I can not find the folder: SyntaxTree\

How can I use this version in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a little confusion here. The UnityVS releases are named after their Visual Studio counter part.

So if you're using Visual Studio 2010, you need to install UnityVS 2010 and import the UnityVS 2010 package in your Unity project.

Same goes for VS 2012 and 2013.